# In Django REST control serializer does not automatically remove spaces？

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

model.py

```
class Msg(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Msg
        fields = ["content"]
```

have data：

```
{"content": "   space    test    "}
```

and

```
print(data)
serializer = MessageSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    print(serializer.data)
    return True, serializer.data
else:
    return False, serializer.errors
```

first print is 
`{'content': '      space      test           '}`

second print is 
`{'content': 'space      test'}`

So the spaces in the database disappeared.
How do I keep spaces?

Comment: pls remove all the backticks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [DRF docs on CharField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield):

> `trim_whitespace` - If set to True then leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed. Defaults to True.

So you need to pass this flag to the serializer field yourself and set it to `False`:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.CharField(trim_whitespace=False, max_length=1024)
    class Meta:
        model = Msg
        fields = ["content"]
```

or better via [additional keyword arguments](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments):

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Msg
        fields = ["content"]
        extra_kwargs = {"content": {"trim_whitespace": False}}
```

The second variant is better because the other properties will still be properly picked up from the model by DRF.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the output of that field by implement the method to_representation()

Answer (score 1):

You can use **trim_whitespace** option given in django-rest-framework serializers.

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=1024, trim_whitespace=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Msg
        fields = ["content"]
```